# Reorder variables in a ggplot graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble to represent several variables in a concrete order. I obtained variables in alphabetic order by default, but I want to order them in function of their nature (showing first climatic variables, morphological variables and finally ecological variables, in my case). How can I achieve this?
Here is the code that I am using:

````
pdf("posterior_means.pdf", width=8, height=6)

ggplot(EstimatesMCMC, aes(Predictor, Mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point( colour = 'black', size = 3) +
  labs(y = "Posterior distribution") +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size = 12)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "grey", size=1) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = `LowerCI`, ymax = `UpperCI`))```

Predictor variables are represented in Y axe, while X axe shows posterior distribution range. 

I really appreaciate any comments
````

Comment: Hi OP, you'll want to set the levels of the column via `factor(... , levels=)` prior to plotting.  Without a representative example, it's hard to offer more support.  You can specify `levels=` manually, but I would recommend, (1) group your dataframe by your grouping variable, (2) apply a new ordering if you need to, (3) set the levels based on that particular order.  Depends on what the dataframe looks like.

Comment: Hi, thats my dataframe looks:     Predictor LowerCI Mean UpperCI
Temperature 1,103450 1,321270 1,558359
Radiation 0,5196805 0,6963046 0,9059417
Wind speed -0,5603989 -0,3723035 -0,2111619
Latitude -0,3181382 -0,1045898 0,1045085
Body Mass -5,479218 -1,796575 1,562540
Tarsus lenght -0,788459 2,299675 5,612284
Foraging:Open 0,5471171 6,068451 12,405987
Foraging:Wading -4,462589 -0,9187676 2,622324
Plumage Score -2,368234 -0,253684 1,856699

Answer (score 0):

OP, you have a few options for sorting variables on your axis according to a category.  It's not very easy to demonstrate with the data you shared, so I'll demonstrate two methods using a representative example dataset.

The example data below contains 3 columns:  **category** is the general category for the variable (one of 3), **my_variable** is the column used for the x axis.  You'll see in the plot below the x axis is in alphabetic order, and I'll show you how we can get it in "category" order.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(8675309)

df <- data.frame(
  category = sample(c('Category A','Category B','Category C'), 26, replace=TRUE),
  my_variable =LETTERS,
  values = rnorm(26, 10, 5)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=my_variable, y=values)) + geom_col(aes(fill=category))
p
```

[image]

#### Method 1: Defining Levels in a Factor

The ordering of the column labels will be determined first by the order of `levels` if it is a factor.  Otherwise, `ggplot2` will default to alphanumeric.  Therefore, you can set the order by converting that column to a factor and setting the `levels=` argument.  In this case, we will want to factorize the column "my_variable".  First, we'll want to put it in order.

```
df_ordered <- df %>%
  dplyr::arrange(category)
```

If you plot `df_ordered` in the same way as before, you'll still get `my_variable` organized alphabetically.  The reason is that we have not set that column as a factor.  We want to do that and specify that the `levels=` of that factor should use the order in which the values appear in the dataframe.  In this case, we only have one `value` per each `my_variable`.  If we had more than one value for each `my_variable`, we would want to specify each item in `my_variable` only once in the `levels=` argument, so this is why I'm writing it to be more general using `unique()`:

```
df_ordered$my_variable <- factor(df_ordered$my_variable,
  levels=unique(df_ordered$my_variable))
```

Now when you plot, the order is determined by the ordering of the levels of the factor `df_ordered$my_variable`.  We specified the levels of that factor via the order in which the levels appear in the ordered dataset, so this works fine now:

```
ggplot(df_ordered, aes(x=my_variable, y=values)) + geom_col(aes(fill=category))
```

[image]

#### Method 2: Use Faceting

The alternative to setting levels and reordering your dataframe is to do the grouping via the plot.  The easiest way to do this is by faceting your plot.

```
p + facet_grid(~category, scales='free_x', space="free_x")
```

[image]

You can still get this to "look" a bit more like the other plot (no spaces in-between) with a bit of fancy formatting.  Here's some options that you can see we can change to mess around with how the final plot looks:

```
p + facet_grid(~category, scales='free_x', space="free_x", switch = "x") +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0, 'pt'),
    strip.placement = 'outside',
    strip.background = element_rect(fill='NA', color='black'),
    strip.text = element_text(size=11, face='bold')
  )
```

[image]

Play around with those settings and you can probably get it to look the way you want.